# WP7 - AppHub submision fails with error code 1044

Tags: windows-phone-7

I just tried submitting my app to AppHub for the first time and I keep getting a submission failure. This is the error:

```
Error code: 1044
The XAP uses one or more restricted native APIs.
```

I found [this](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/63650.aspx) post describing the same error but he says his problem was solved by adding the `/NOENTRY` linker option to his resource-only DLL (used for application name localization). I already have that option set in my localization DLL, yet the submission fails.

Has anyone come across this, and hopefully found a solution?

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:**

Turns out it was the localization DLL, just the presence of a DLL in the XAP was causing that error. Since I'm not supporting any languages other than English right now I just removed the DLL from the project and submitted it. It'd be nice to figure out a solution though.

**EDIT2**

I have been googling this for a while now and found some blogs about how to localize the application title. All of them call the DLL AppResLib.dll and place it at the root of the application project. I not only gave my DLL another name but also placed it within a Resources subdirectory. I guess one or both of those things are what's causing the error. Unfortunately I won't be able to test this theory out until I submit an update.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've mentioned localizing, [I wrote a blog on the subject](http://hopnet.mobi/website/Blog.aspx). But of note is your mention of the dlls that you need to create when you localize an app. I see that you're not localizing this app, but if you should choose to do so later, or with another app, there is [a good tool](http://patrickgetzmann.wordpress.com/wp7-localize/), mentioned in my blog, that will create the dlls for you. You put in the Title, it translates, you direct it to the folder to save in, and it creates all the dlls.